# MacBook Pro crashes and panic after Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I have updated from OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion to OS X 10.10 Yosemite 6 months ago and since then my Mac freezes with no reason (I need to switch off the computer). 
Yesterday after installing a Yosemite update and restaring the Mac I got this message

```
Anonymous UUID:       817CBB7E-FDC5-902F-E2CE-232D99474A7A

Fri Aug 21 08:40:05 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802cfc127e): "launchd died\nState at Last Exception:\n\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.40.9/bsd/kern/kern_exit.c:363

uuid info:
 0x7fff6e526000 uuid = <b1b370a5-479f-3533-8ad7-97b687d4f989>
 0x10b775000    uuid = <c0446878-e8d0-3461-a226-91ff1c2b2da6>
 0x10b7c5000    uuid = <4396b358-725e-3ec0-bcbb-e4bf75fe1fb0>

RAX: 0x0000000002000001, RBX: 0x0000000000000006, RCX: 0x000000010c2510e8, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0x000000010c2510e8, RBP: 0x000000010c251190, RSI: 0x000000010c250f40, RDI: 0x0000000000000001
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x000000010b7b49f0, R10: 0x00007fff951b6b02, R11: 0x0000000000000206
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x00007fff94c317e0, R14: 0x000000010c2515d0, R15: 0x000000010c251790
RFL: 0x0000000000000206, RIP: 0x00007fff951b495a, CS:  0x0000000000000007, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread  0xffffff80386c02e0
    0x00007fff8b262dab
    0x00007fff8b262ec8
    0x00007fff8b25c3b4
    0x00007fff8f3daa6c
    0x000000010b7a3907
    0x00007fff894bcc13
    0x00007fff894bf88f
    0x00007fff894cdfe4
    0x00007fff88ebca9d
    0x00007fff88eba3dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff803873ca78
    0x00007fff894bfa6a
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff803898aa78
    0x000000010b78cc91
    0x00007fff894bcc13
    0x00007fff894c0365
    0x00007fff894c1ecc
    0x00007fff894bf6b7
    0x00007fff894cdfe4
    0x00007fff88ebca9d
    0x00007fff88eba3dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff803898a108
    0x00007fff894cd3ad
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff8045c57000
    0x00007fff941dbf1a
    0x0000000000000001
    0x00007fff6e532475
    0x00007fff8743e7b5
    0x00007fff8b231648
    0x00007fff94c317e0
    0x00007fff94c33ddf
    0x00007fff894bcc13
    0x00007fff894bde5e
    0x00007fff94c320a7
    0x000000010b7a0393
    0x00007fff894bcc13
    0x00007fff894c0365
    0x00007fff894c1ecc
    0x00007fff894c0154
    0x00007fff894c1ecc
    0x00007fff894bf6b7
    0x00007fff894cdfe4
    0x00007fff88ebca9d
    0x00007fff88eba3dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff8044333e28
    0x00007fff8b23040f
    0x000000010b7844dd
    0x000000010b78a264
    0x00007fff894bcc13
    0x00007fff894c787e
    0x00007fff894c062b
    0x00007fff894c0154
    0x00007fff894c1ecc
    0x00007fff894bf6b7
    0x00007fff894cdfe4
    0x00007fff88ebca9d
    0x00007fff88eba3dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80462705c0
    0x00007fff894c787e
    0x00007fff894c062b
    0x00007fff894c0154
    0x00007fff894c1ecc
    0x00007fff894bf6b7
    0x00007fff894bf453
    0x00007fff88ebd05a
    0x00007fff88ebcfd7
    0x00007fff88eba3ed
    0x0000000000000000

Mac OS version: 14F27
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)
```

Any suggestions? Is it going to break soon?

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread on the Apple forum, with a possible solution:

> 1. Go to "Activity Monitor" - you should see launchd using lots of CPU resources - and I think this is why it's crashing intermittently.  The Mac is going nuts trying to launch something which it can't and it finally resets itself.
> 2. Go to "Console" and look up System Log Queries - All Messages - it's going to be pretty obvious what launchd is trying to er, launch.  On my computer it was trying to launch this: /Library/eBookLibrary/eBook Library Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/eBook Library Launcher
> 3. Go to /Library/LaunchAgents - you will see the plist file that the launchd is trying to launch - in my case it was the Sony ebook reader plist.  I deleted it without any problems.
> 4. Restart the system.
> 5. Go back to "Activity Monitor" - you should no longer see launchd hogging the resources.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6612843)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this guide, I installed Yosemite 2017 security patch and my mac would continually crash a few minutes after booting (xnu kernel panic).

In System Log Queries I found it handy to install several log markers after the logging went quiet. Then after the crash and subsequent reboot I would look in /var/log/system.log for those markers and read the entries before the reboot.

In my case, I found deleting /System/Library/LaunchAgents/*cloud* (after backing up) fixed the kernel panic issue.